# Why IDE shows me error when I import SVG file to use as React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, next.js

I am try to using SVG Icon as React component with `svgr`

everything works well. I can imoport SVG and svgr convert it to ReactComponents perfectly.

but, My IDE webstorm still shows me error when I import svg like below

[image]

I am using typescript and nextjs as well.

what is real problem? is it only caused by IDE? or Should I setup additional options?

here is my config files

#### tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": "src/"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.svg"
  ]
}
```

#### next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    // Note: we provide webpack above so you should not `require` it
    // Perform customizations to webpack config
    // Important: return the modified config
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\/__tests__\//))

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: [{
        loader: '@svgr/webpack',
        options: {
          svgoConfig: {
            plugins: {
              removeViewBox: false
            }
          }
        }
      }],
    })
    return config
  },
  webpackDevMiddleware: (config) => {
    // Perform customizations to webpack dev middleware config
    // Important: return the modified config
    return config
  },
}
```

and no babelrc because I am using default babel setting given by nextjs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I find by my self. It is caused by typescript. i had to declare type for `.svg`

I made typing.d.ts file on the root

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import * as React from 'react';

  export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;

  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

The IDE does not show error any more